# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token Android Studio API 23

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio

We have a WebView app that works on some devices and on others it won't, these are the same devices, same OS (Android 6), same apps installed...

My guess is that something is not updated... The default browser is the same...

It also throws "Uncaught syntax error" on many javascript files as if it's not able to run javascript, this happens with webview, cordova apps, NET MAUI webview, NET MAUI with Blazor bindings.

As I said it works on almost all devices but there are a few where it doesn't.

```
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(20)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )", source: http://example.com/js/bootstrap.min.js (20)
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(365)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 't' has already been declared", source: http://example.com/js/bootbox.all.min.js (365)
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(116)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [", source: http://xampp.geinal.com:33432/js/funcs.js (116)
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )", source: http://example.com/_framework/blazor.server.js (1)
```

- The model is Chainway c6000 (Android 6 NOT 10, the model with 10 also works fine)
- Don't take the logs as an absolute reference but the idea that JS won't work.

Edit: MainActivity.java code

```
package com.example.testview;

import static com.google.android.material.internal.ContextUtils.getActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.net.http.SslError;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.core.content.FileProvider;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

import com.example.testview.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.SslErrorHandler;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webView;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private String mCM;
    private ValueCallback mUM;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mUMA;
    private final static int FCR=1;



    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){





         int _result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        // int _result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        if (_result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Log.d("-----------------CODE X","Hay permisos");
        } else {
            Log.d("-----------------CODE X","ERROR permisos");
        }


        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){
            Uri[] results = null;
            //Check if response is positive
            if(resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK){
              if(requestCode == FCR){
                    if(null == mUMA){
                        Log.d("-----------------CODE 0","ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR");
                         return;
                    }
                    if(intent == null || intent.getData() == null){
                        //Capture Photo if no image available
                        if(mCM != null){

                            Log.d("-----------------CODE 1",new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCM)}.toString());
                            Log.d("----------------CODE R3", String.valueOf(results));

                            results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCM)};
                        }
                    }else{
                        String dataString = intent.getDataString();
                        if(dataString != null){
                            Log.d("-----------------CODE 2",new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)}.toString());
                            Log.d("-----------------CODE D",dataString);
                            Log.d("----------------CODE R2", String.valueOf(results));

                            results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            Log.d("----------------CODE R1", String.valueOf(results));

            mUMA.onReceiveValue(results);
            mUMA = null;
        }else{
            if(requestCode == FCR){
                if(null == mUM) return;
                Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
                mUM.onReceiveValue(result);
                mUM = null;
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint({"SetJavaScriptEnabled", "WrongViewCast"})
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


      // if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
          //      ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 3);
             //   ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 3);
          //  }



        Log.d("-----------------CODE C","ONCREATEONCREATEONCREATEONCREATEONCREATEONCREATEONCREATEONCREATEONCREATEONCREATEONCREATE");


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=23 && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1);
        }


        // Andorid 10 filechooser not showing camera option
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1);
        }

        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);



        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.MyWeb);
        //    assert webView != null;
        //  WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);

        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);

        webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);

        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){
            webView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(0);
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        }else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19){
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        }else {
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }
        webView.setWebViewClient(new Callback());



         webView.loadUrl("http://192.168.56.154");



        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
            private ValueCallback<Uri[]> uploadMessage;

            //For Android 5.0+
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams){
                Log.d("Message tag -2 File cho","onShowFileChooser done");





                if(mUMA != null){
                    mUMA.onReceiveValue(null);
                }

                mUMA = filePathCallback;
                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                if(takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(MainActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null){
                    File photoFile = null;
                    try{
                        photoFile = createImageFile();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCM);
                    }catch(IOException ex){
                        Log.e(TAG, "Image file creation failed", ex);
                    }
                    if(photoFile != null){
                        mCM = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                    }else{
                        takePictureIntent = null;
                    }
                }

                Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                contentSelectionIntent.setType("*/*");
                Intent[] intentArray;

                if(takePictureIntent != null){
                    intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
                }else{
                    intentArray = new Intent[0];
                }

                Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                //    Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FCR);
                return true;


            }
        });
    }




    public class Callback extends WebViewClient{

        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            handler.proceed();
        }


        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed loading app!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    // Create an image file
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException{


        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "img_"+timeStamp+"_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        return File.createTempFile(imageFileName,".jpg",storageDir);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, @NonNull KeyEvent event){
        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            switch(keyCode){
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if(webView.canGoBack()){
                        webView.goBack();
                    }else{
                        finish();
                    }
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
/*
    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
        handler.proceed(); // Ignore SSL certificate errors
    }
*/


    @Override

    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

Edit 2:
I did some testing and found that the "UserAgent:Browser = CHROME_MOBILE" is the same on both, but there is a difference in "UserAgent:BrowserVersion = 75.0", that's the one working, and the one that doesn't is "UserAgent:BrowserVersion = 44.0".

Comment: share with us the source code

Comment: I don't expect it to be a code thing, since there are some devices (the same exact model and android version) that can run the app with no errors. Still, I'm uploading the android studio main activity that has the webview.

Comment: Android 6 WebView package is not linked to Chrome app so updating chrome doesn't update the WebView and you are stuck with an outdated version that is missing JavaScript functionality needed for the framework to work. This was changed in Android 7.0, if you update chrome, WebView is also updated and everything works again. This device was stuck in Android 6 so What we did to solve this is we contacted the manufacturer, they sent the latest Android 6.0 os they had, Wich had a more recent WebView , we updated the device and then both had version 75. (we updated from Android 6 to other android 6)